# SQL Server - Non-distributed transaction over two DBs

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I am trying to localize an issue I have 
with 2 DBs and their transactional behavior.

I create two DBs on a single SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

test1
test2

test1 has one table Table_1
test2 has one table Table_2

Both tables have an ID (int) and a value (string) columns.
Both have just one row which has ID=1.

Then in SQL Server Management Studio,
in some window 1 I do

```
use test1

begin transaction

update test1.dbo.Table_1
set
value = 'TEST-100'
where
ID = 1 


update test2.dbo.Table_2
set
value = 'TEST-200'
where
ID = 1 

commit transaction  --- but I don’t run the commit yet ---
```

and then in another window 2, I do

```
select * From test1.dbo.Table_1
with (nolock) 

select * From test2.dbo.Table_2
with (nolock)
```

This way I can see the two uncommitted yet values.

But if in window 2, I do

```
select * From test1.dbo.Table_1
```

or

```
select * From test2.dbo.Table_2
```

these SELECT staments hang.

So my question is: is that transaction from
window 1, spanning two DBs? Seems so because

```
select * From test2.dbo.Table_2
```

hangs too which means to me that test2.dbo.Table_2
is enlisted in the same transaction which I started
in window 1.

But why is this transaction acting like a distributed one?
Is that normal? What is the explanation? Is that some 
undocummented feature in SQL Server? Are there any 
references which would explain that behavior I am seeing?

Answer (score 1):

When a query spans over 2 databases, then your transaction is promoted to a distributed transaction handled by MSDTC. It's the normal way to be and it happens without explicitly using BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION statement.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Could you point me to some references?

Comment: Use this link as entry point: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191440(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It is not handled by MSDTC (I know because my MSDTC is disabled and it works). It is handled internally to SQL Server. I also do not think that it has the properties of a DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION.

Comment: @usr: "When a distributed query is executed in a local transaction, the transaction is automatically promoted to a distributed transaction", link: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188386.aspx. Have you downvoted this answer?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted and I proved this answer wrong (disable MSDTC and try it). Using multiple DBs in a tran only uses distributed transactions if done on multiple connections or across servers. The docs you refer to are valid for true distributed transactions, but they are not used here.